# Доступ к CSS-классам

Tags: css3, css, html

Скажите, пожалуйста, (так как не очень дружу с CSS), есть вот такая html:

```
<div id="mydiv1" class="parent child-1 panda" >Word1</div>

<div id="mydiv2" class="parent child-2 panda" >Word3</div>

<div id="mydiv3" class="parent child-1 panda2" >Word2</div>
```

Как получить доступ по этим классам (родитель - ребенок - внук, и т.д.)?
Например, можно ли так:

```
.parent child-1 panda {...}
.panda2 {...}
```

Comment: плохой вопрос, почитай про цсс, фигню спрашиваешь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В атрибуте `class` вы записываете список классов, которые присущи данному div. Т.е. браузер будет пытаться искать css-свойства каждого из этих классов. А в файле стилей .css к ним можно получить доступ так:

```
.parent { ... }
.child-1 { ... }
.panda2 { ... }
```

Если ваши элементы находятся друг в друге, например:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
      <div class="vnuk">
...
</div></div></div>
```

то получить доступ к элементу c классом vnuk, можно перечисляя последовательно все div (т.е. так как они находятся в документе):

```
.parent .child .vnuk {...}
или просто
.vnuk {...} ("внук" у нас один, если было бы много, то такое объявление применялось бы ко всем "внукам", найденным в документе)
```

Можно также через id обратиться, например:

```
#mydiv2 { ... }
```

(т.е. через точку вы записываете названия классов, а через решетку id)
Если вы в атрибуте class запишете, например:

```
<div class="child vnuk">
```

то это значит, что свойства будут браться сначала из класса child, а потом из класса vnuk.

Comment: если child-1,child-2,child-3....
можно ли не каждого перечислять, а сразу child{} указать(опускать нумераций)?

Comment: Вы можете сделать общее правило с именем класса .child И потом всем элементам дописывать этот класс. Можете еще через запятую перечислить все ваши элементы с одинаковыми свойствами:

    .child-1, .child-2, .child-3 {color:black}

Comment: ух, французский с нижегородским... детский селектор `A > B`, а не `A B` который выбирает потомка.

Comment: @karmadro4, это если только настолько точно нужно. Пускай так хотя бы пока учится. А то так автор добавит еще один какой-нибудь div и будет материться почему ничего не работает.

Comment: В вашем примере нужен непосредственный потомок. Зачем учите делать неправильно?

Comment: @karmadro4, непосредственные потомки не работают в IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Через точку.

```
.parent.child-1.panda {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Пример.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bumbay/9UWAD/)